# Is the Series Convergent or Divergent? Find Sum

Tags: calculus

$$\sum^\infty_{n=4}\frac{3^{2n}}{(-10)^n}$$
which can get to look like

$$\sum^\infty_{n=4}\frac{9^{n}}{(-10)^n}$$
which i know can now prove that it converges because $\frac{9}{10}<1$ 
Now i have to find what it actually converges too and this is where i'm having trouble. do i just plug in the 4?

Comment: $\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{9}{10}$ is divergent. So your reasoning is not correct.  Just like $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sum^{\infty}q^n,$ where $|q|<1$, it is equal $$\frac{\text{the first item}}{1-q}.$$

So $$\sum^\infty_{n=4}\frac{9^{n}}{(-10)^n}=\frac{\frac{9^4}{(-10)^4}}{1-(-\frac{9}{10})}$$